# How do I convert 'Month(String) YYYY' to 'YYYY-MM-DD' in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data like below :

```
|   |Period         | Total
--------------------------------
|0  |January 2000   |49045412
|1  |February 2000  |49306303
|2  |March 2000     |60443541
|3  |April 2000     |58286680
|4  |May 2000       |60533783
```

To convert Period column to the desired output, I tried valid conversion which should work

```
time['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Period'])
```

It's working for most of the month's but failing for a few months as shown below

```
|   |Period         | Total     |Month
-----------------------------------------
0   |January 2000   |49045412   |2000-01-01
1   |February 2000  |49306303   |2000-02-01
2   |March 2000     |60443541   |2000-03-01
3   |April 2000     |58286680   |2000-04-01
4   |May 2000       |60533783   |2000-05-01
5   |June 2000      |64903295   |NaT
6   |July 2000      |67346377   |NaT
7   |August 2000    |66256804   |NaT
8   |September 2000 |55900504   |NaT
9   |October 2000   |58373996   |NaT
10  |November 2000  |55590325   |NaT
11  |December 2000  |54822970   |NaT
```

Answer (score 2):

What you tried works for me, more specific one could be using `format` arg of `to_datetime`.

```
df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Period, format='%B %Y')
```

**Output**

```
    Period          Total       Month
0   January 2000    49045412    2000-01-01
1   February 2000   49306303    2000-02-01
2   March 2000      60443541    2000-03-01
3   April 2000      58286680    2000-04-01
4   May 2000        60533783    2000-05-01
5   June 2000       64903295    2000-06-01
6   July 2000       67346377    2000-07-01
7   August 2000     66256804    2000-08-01
8   September 2000  55900504    2000-09-01
9   October 2000    58373996    2000-10-01
10  November 2000   55590325    2000-11-01
11  December 2000   54822970    2000-12-01
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d = ['September 2021', 'September 2000', 'April 2000']
df = pd.DataFrame({'period': d})
```

before:

```
    period
0   September 2021
1   September 2000
2   April 2000
```

the fix:

```
df.period = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.period)
```

after:

```
    period
0   2021-09-01
1   2000-09-01
2   2000-04-01
```